# Identical learning curves on subsequent runs using ShuffleSplit

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm having a particularly bizarre issue with learning curve generation in scikit-learn. Subsequent runs of a script that generates a learning curve returns identical results. If I change any parameters of the ShuffleSplit object, or the learning curve object, I'll get different results in between runs. But if I leave those parameters the same, the output will be identical.

I set the ShuffleSplit object to use 10% for training and 10% for testing, and 3 iterations. I did this to avoid the possibility that the contents of the training/testing sets were the same even if they were ordered differently. The ShuffleSplit is supposed to take random indices to generate each of the sets (and I've validated that it does so). So, if the training sets are different in subsequent runs, even slightly, a Bayes model should have different train and test errors, right?

It almost appears as though the scores are being cached and until the parameters for the ShuffleSplit object or learning_curve method, it just returns the cached result. I can't think of any other explanation. Any ideas??

Here's a simplified example of the issue, based of the scikit-learn example code and data set at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_learning_curve.html:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.learning_curve import learning_curve


def plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, X, y, ylim=None, cv=None,
                        n_jobs=1, train_sizes=np.linspace(.1, 1.0, 5)):
    plt.figure()
    plt.title(title)
    if ylim is not None:
        plt.ylim(*ylim)
    plt.xlabel("Training examples")
    plt.ylabel("Score")
    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
        estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes)
    train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.grid()

    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                     train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.1,
                     color="r")
    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                     test_scores_mean + test_scores_std, alpha=0.1, color="g")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color="r",
             label="Training score")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g",
             label="Cross-validation score")

    plt.legend(loc="best")
    return plt


digits = load_digits()
X, y = digits.data, digits.target

title = "Learning Curves (Naive Bayes)"
cv = cross_validation.ShuffleSplit(digits.data.shape[0], n_iter=3, 
                                   train_size=0.2, test_size=0.1, 
                                   random_state=0)

estimator = GaussianNB()
plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, X, y, ylim=(0.7, 1.01), cv=cv, n_jobs=1)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actively change the random seed of the `ShuffleSplit` object using the keyword argument `random_state`.

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import ShuffleSplit
cv = ShuffleSplit(n_samples, n_iter=10, test_size=.1, random_state=42)
```

By changing this every time you create the cv object, you should obtain different results.

Comment: That did the trick, but I'm still confused about what's going on. The ShuffleSplit class returns two lists of indices - one for the train set and one for the test set. I verified these indices are different on subsequent runs, so what exactly is the random_state variable doing if it's not related to the indices?

Comment: One cross validation run consists of `n_iter` splits of the data. These are all different (with extremely high probability) because they are randomly selected sequentially. However, if you fix the seed to some integer, then the entirety of the cv, i.e. all `n_iter` splits will be exactly the same, even if you generate them twice. This is because just before generation, a random number generator is initialized with the seed and then numbers are drawn from it. These numbers are completely deterministic. By changing the seed you will obtain a different cv object which splits completely differentl

Comment: it looks like if the `random_state` parameter is not specified it will also be different every time. I suppose it's useful to specify the random_state if you want other people to be able to reproduce results exactly.